# How to define a DateProperty object in App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am facing difficulties in creating dateproperty object and I can't seems to create the object. Here is my code:

```
from google.appengine.ext import db

class Baby(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    dob = db.DateProperty()

for i in Baby.all():
    delete(i)

Baby(name='wilson', dob=Date(year=1986,month=3,day=5)).put()
```

Is there anything wrong with my code?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5):

The value of a DateProperty will need to be a datetime.date object, as mentioned here: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#DateProperty

So, you will need to add:

```
import datetime
```

and also change dob=Date(year=1986, month=3, day=5) to:

```
dob = datetime.date(year=1986, month=3, day=5)
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Elliot said, db.DateProperty() accepts only datetime.date object.To know more about datetime you can see [here](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html).This datetime.date propery gives you much more flexibiliy and opeartions. And also using timedelta you can do much more manipulation like adding one day ahead and so.
so you have to import date time as

```
from datetime import date
year=self.request.get['year']
month=self.request.get['month']
day=self.request.get['day']
dob=date(int(year),int(month),int(day))
baby=Baby()
baby.name='wilson'
baby.date=dob
baby.put()
```